Kunen's "Set Theory", Chapter 1, Exercise 22
The following appears as Exercise 22, Chapter 1 in Kunen's Set Theory: An Introduction to Independence Proofs:
Assume $\operatorname{Con}(\sf ZF)$. Show that there is a formula $\psi(x)$ such that $\psi$ represents $E=\lbrace n: \text{n is even} \rbrace$ but
$$\text{ZF} \nvDash \forall x \in \omega(\psi(x) \vee \psi(x+\left\ulcorner 1 \right\urcorner)).
$$
Here "$\psi$ represents the set of even numbers" means: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$
n \in E \rightarrow (\text{ZF} \vdash \psi(\ulcorner n\urcorner)) \text{ and } n \notin E \rightarrow (\text{ZF} \vdash \neg \psi(\ulcorner n \urcorner))
$$
So, somehow, one is asked to cook up a pathological definition of "even", but I have no idea how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The standard approach is to simply take:
\begin{equation*}\psi(x)=\exists k\in \omega\:(\forall c\leq k \;(c \text{ is not a proof of} \bot\text{ from the axioms of } ZF)\wedge x=2k
\end{equation*} Since $ZF$ cannot prove $Con(ZF)$ it cannot prove $\forall x\in \omega\;(\psi(x)\vee \psi(x+1))$.
